# Detect Alpha Channel with ImageMagick

Tags: image, png, imagemagick, jpeg, alpha

#### Scenario

I would like to save images with alpha transparency as `.png` and images without alpha transparency as `.jpg` (even if their original format is `.png` or `.gif`).  How can I detect whether or not an image has alpha transparency using ImageMagick?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The ImageMagik command:

```
identify -format '%[channels]' foo.png
```

will print `rgba` or `rgb` if there is or is not an alpha channel, respectively.

There could be an alpha channel present with no data in it which wouldn't actually have any transparency, but that is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Is it common for there to be an alpha channel with no data in it?  If so, can I find that out?

Comment: In my experience, people only create alpha channels when they want them to be non-empty, but there is a difference between what usually happens and what can happen. I wouldn't worry about it unless you find it popping up. I was just trying to be complete by noting the existence of an alpha channel does not necessarily imply the presence of transparency.

Comment: Ah, yes.  Never underestimate the user.  Thanks!

Comment: This is a very old question to be sure, but the absence of an alpha channel does not imply the absence of alpha pixels.  It's possible to have an indexed RGB png with some of the index entries completely transparent.  See tRNS in the png documentation.

Answer (score 39):

#### Check if the image has an alpha channel

Use **`-format %A`**, as per [serhiy.h's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20385050/1160124).  From the [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php):

> `%A`    image transparency channel. Values include Undefined (no transparency channel), Blend, Copy, or Update.

#### Check if the image has no transparent or translucent pixels

Use **`-format %[opaque]`**.  From the [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php):

> `%[opaque]`    CALCULATED: is image fully-opaque?

---

#### Example

To demonstrate, lets create an image `a.png` that has an alpha channel but is fully opaque, and an image `b.png` that is the same except for one translucent pixel:

```
$ convert rose: PNG32:a.png
$ convert rose: -fill '#0008' -draw "matte 10,10 point" PNG32:b.png
```

As expected, the `%A` escape produces `Blend` for both images, since both have an alpha channel:

```
$ identify -format '%A' a.png
Blend
$ identify -format '%A' b.png  
Blend
```

Whereas the `%[opaque]` escape produces `true` in one case, and `false` in the other due to the one transparent pixel:

```
$ identify -format '%[opaque]' a.png
true
$ identify -format '%[opaque]' b.png
false
```

Comment: Thanks! With an output like that it's even tempting to do `if $(identify -format '%[opaque]' "$file"); then ...; fi`

Comment: I've spent *all day* looking for `%[opaque]`, THANK YOU

Comment: Full CLI command `magick identify -format '%[opaque]' file.png`

Answer (score 32):

**If you want to check that a picture is actually transparent... (not only an alpha channel which might be unused)**

Use this command:

```
convert some_pic.png -verbose info:
```

(yes, there is a `:` at the end of the command)

It is quite verbose. Look for the channels list:

```
(...)
Channel depth:
  red: 16-bit
  green: 16-bit
  blue: 16-bit
Channel statistics:
(...)
```

In this example, there are three channels, one for each primary color. But non for alpha. So this image is not transparent.

But you can also get this kind of output:

```
(...)
Channel depth:
  red: 16-bit
  green: 16-bit
  blue: 16-bit
  alpha: 1-bit
Channel statistics:
(...)
```

Here, there is an alpha channel. However, this does no prove that the image is transparent. It just says that it *might* be. In the outputs of the command, look for the information about alpha channel:

```
(...)
  Alpha:
    min: 255 (1)
    max: 255 (1)
    mean: 255 (1)
    standard deviation: 0 (0)
    kurtosis: 0
    skewness: 0
(...)
```

In this example, the alpha says that the picture is opaque: `min` = `max` = 1 (1 = opaque, 0 = transparent). So even if the image has an alpha channel, the user sees an opaque picture.

You can also get this:

```
(...)
  Alpha:
    min: 95 (0.372549)
    max: 212 (0.831373)
    mean: 111.187 (0.436028)
    standard deviation: 19.5635 (0.0767196)
    kurtosis: 7.52139
    skewness: -2.80445
(...)
```

This time, `min` = 0.372549. This means that some pixels are partly transparent. `mean` is also low. It seems that a large part of the image uses transparency.

Depending of the type of check you want to achieve (full opacity, "almost opaque", etc.), you should check `min`, `mean` and maybe `standard deviation` if your request is a bit tricky.

Note: you might be tempted to check integer values for `min`, `mean` and others, as I did in the first place. After all, it is easier to deal with `95` than `0.372549`. If you choose this route, beware the alpha channel depth. If it is 8 bits, then 255 is the maximum and means "opaque". If it is 16 bits, the maximum is now 65535 and 255 means "almost transparent". Better check the floats in parenthesis, which always range from 0 to 1.

If you suspect that a lot of pictures you will process have no alpha channel at all, it might be useful to first run:

```
identify -format '%[channels]' some_pic.png
```

If it dumps:

```
rgba
```

there is an alpha channel (the `a` in the output) and `convert` should be used to check `min`, etc.. But if there isn't, there is no need to run `convert`. Although I didn't benchmarked these two commands, `identify` should be much faster than `convert`.

Comment: For many users, folks who just want to see if the alpha channel is necessary, grabbing the alpha min line and checking that it ends with "(1)" or not should be sufficient.

Comment: thank you for a detailed answer. this actually provides some deeper insight into accessing image's properties and doesn't simply answer the OP's question, but also expands on it.

Answer (score 7):

```
identify -format %A some_pic.png
```

Will return `True` if image contains alpha channel.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure that alpha transparency is really used, the only solution I see it to iterate all pixels and get the color info to check if it's transparent or not. For large images this will be very slow, so, as an optimization you can first make a thumbnail of the image (let's say 20x20) and then check the thumbnail pixels. This was a good solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple of bash functions to check if a png has transparency or not, using ImageMagick.

Fast check, which just checks for the *presence* of an alpha channel:

```
checkAlphaFast() {
    test $(identify -format %A "$1") == True
}
```

Slow check, verifies the pixels themselves (even if alpha channel is present):

```
checkAlphaSlow() {
    test $(identify -format '%[opaque]' "$1") == false
}
```

You should only consider using the fast check if you're doing this a whole lot, because it's pretty fast either way. Thanks to the other people who answered, from which I made these functions :)

As a bonus: I did not make any benchmarking, but this may be almost as fast as the fast mode and as accurate as the slow mode:

```
checkAlpha() {
    checkAlphaFast "$1" && checkAlphaSlow "$1"
}
```

Use these functions like this:

```
if checkAlpha "$myPNG"; then
    # is transparent
else
    # is opaque
fi
```

---

And this will give you the opaqueness of the image, where 0 is fully transparent and 1 is fully opaque:

```
checkOpaqueness() {
    if checkAlphaFast "$1"; then
        convert "$1" -verbose info: | grep -A3 Alpha: | tail +4 | head -n1 | sed -r 's/.*\(|\)//g'
    else
        echo 1
    fi
}
```

And this one outputs as a rounded percentage, because integers are so much more natural for bash:

```
checkPercentage() {
    printf %3.2f $(checkOpaqueness "$1") | tr -d . | sed -r 's/^0?0?//'
}
```