# Imagemagick: remove alpha component (replace all intermediate alpha pixel with solid pixel)

Tags: image-processing, command-line, imagemagick

To solve [Android build issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469807/android-studio-shows-errorframe-pixels-must-be-either-solid-or-transparent-not) I need to replace all intermediate alpha pixel with solid pixel (leaving transparent background as is).

How to that with ImageMagick or other-command line tool to all images in a tree?

Image  bg_all_block.9.png

[image: bg_all_block.9.png]

Image btn_bg_common_press.9.png

[image: btn_bg_common_press.9.png]

[image]

UPDATE: I have found that I can detect if alpha is used, as in [Detect Alpha Channel with ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581469/detect-alpha-channel-with-imagemagick)

Other found links

- https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16120/batch-replacing-color-with-transparency
- http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#replace

Answer (score 111, accepted):

To remove the alpha channel from single image use this command:

```
convert input.png -alpha off output.png
```

To remove the alpha channel from all images inside a folder, make use `find` to first find all PNG files, and then run 'm through `convert`:

```
find . -name "*.png" -exec convert "{}" -alpha off "{}" \;
```

Please test on a COPY of your files to be sure.

...

see dialog below, and the answer is based on that "we need to remove alpha that is not 255"

```
convert input.png -channel A -threshold 254 output.png
```

and for batch

```
mkdir batch
FOR %G IN (*.png) DO convert %G -channel A -threshold 254 batch\%G
```

Comment: I don't do much Windows but it's probably `mogrify -alpha off *.png`. Not sure if `mogrify` has a `-r` switch for recursing through directories or if it will take `*/*.png`

Comment: Well, I found that this also removes transparent background for my icons.
While I need only process those pixels with intermediate alpha... http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#replace hints at some     `convert balloon.gif  -fill white -opaque blue   balloon_white.gif` Now looking at what `-opaque means`

Comment: Try `-channel A -threshold 254`

Comment: Can you post an image?

Comment: That is clever to say "we need remove alpha that is not 255".

I tried with `convert bg_all_block.9.png -channel A -threshold 254 -alpha off bg_all_block_254.9.png`, but it changes background

Comment: Yes, this is btn_bg_common_press.9.png

Comment: Sorry, I meant for the `-channel A -threshold 254` to fully replace the `-alpha off`, so like this `convert input.png -channel A -threshold 254 output.png`

Comment: You might get on better experimenting with different percentages, like this `convert input.png -channel A -threshold 30% output.png`

Comment: Thank you so much. I have put final result into updated answer and accepted it. ImageMagick is so huge.

Comment: My pleasure, glad to have been of assistance - sorry I was a bit slow to get to the right solution today.

Comment: For macOS users - first you have to install imagemagick. You can do this using brew: `brew install imagemagick`

Comment: When I run `convert input.png -alpha off output.png`, I get an image that is all black. How do I convert transparency to white? I tried `convert input.png -background white -alpha off output.png` with no visible effect.

Comment: But this one works: `convert input.png -background white -alpha remove -flatten -alpha off output.png` https://stackoverflow.com/a/28534287/2374478

Comment: convert: no images defined `./0.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3300.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/556.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me on **macOS** for batch processing was:

```
for f in *.png; do convert "$f" -channel A -threshold 254 "${f%%.png}.png"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove alpha channel from all pictures in the folder (f.ex. all .png files) I use following command (in terminal on **macOS**):

```
for file in *.png; do convert $file -alpha deactivate; done
```

Unfortunately, none of any other solution given in this thread worked for me.