# ImageMagick: how to flatten only a part of an image

Tags: imagemagick, flatten

#### Problem

I’d like to flatten only a part of an image.

#### Image Example

Take for example this image:

[image]

It has transparent background, which I’d like to keep (rather than re-create), also the transparency between the cable casing and the machine (the casing is on the top of the machine). All other transparent parts of the image (i.e. the transparency *in* the machine itself) should be flatten.

#### What I Already Know

I’ve seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937084/imagemagick-remove-alpha-component-replace-all-intermediate-alpha-pixel-with-s) question, but it deals only with not-fully-transparent pixels, however, I’d like to flaten all non-fully-opaque pixels in a part of a image.

I use this command to flatten whole image:

```
convert -flatten input.png output.png
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do, maybe you could add another image showing the expected result please?

In the meanwhile, you can extract the alpha/transparency layer into a separate image that you can play with to you heart's content like this:

```
convert input.png -alpha extract alpha.png
```

[image]

and then merge back into the image with a command like this (but where I create a magenta backdrop instead of using the original image):

```
convert -size 800x600 xc:magenta alpha.png -compose copyalpha -composite result.png
```

[image]

Fill the outer background with cyan like this to keep it as a temporary colour we can find again later:

```
convert alpha.png -fill cyan -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' a.png
```

[image]

Now make everything that is not cyan into white, then everything that is cyan back into black:

```
convert a.png -fuzz 80% -fill white -opaque black -fuzz 5% -fill black -opaque cyan b.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @MarkSetchell. All I want do have is an image with transparent background only. The _thing_ (is in example: the machine) should not be transparent at all in any pixel of the _thing_. I’d like to do it in terminal only, as I’d like to automate the job on user-input image.

Comment: In this particular image, I’d like to remove the transparency from the two rectangles that apear in both of your images.

Comment: So am I correct if I re-state your question as... you'd like to flood-fill all *"holes"* in the alpha layer that would not be flood-filled if you started flood-filling the background from the top-left corner?

Comment: Most-probably yes, I am not certain of the ‘flood-fill’ word meaning. I’d like to flatten all pixels in those ‘holes’.

Comment: I have to run but have put in the outline so you can get started.

Comment: While trying merge the two images, however, I get the following error: `convert: unrecognized compose operator \`copyalpha' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1036.`

Comment: I tried to merge alpha channel from z.png to original image using the following command ([src](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=30341#p136925)): `convert orig.png z.png -alpha off -compose CopyOpacity -composite output.png`, however it does not look good ([output.png](https://imgur.com/a/bkynolP)).

Comment: Back home now. I updated and improved it, so have another look please. If it is jagged, you can blur the alpha mask a bit also (with `-blur 0x3`), or expand it, or contract it (with `-morphology dilate disk:2`).

Comment: I think I was not clear enough: I don’t want to have black background and white machine. :) … I want the image of machine as it is on the original image with transparent background, however, without any alpha colour _in_ the image of the machine. … … So, while the final image of yours might be a step towards my goal, there needs to be yet another command to accomplish this.

Comment: You need to take your original image, turn off its alpha, and then composite the new alpha in its place... `convert original.png -alpha off newalpha.png -compose copyopacity -composite result.png`.

Comment: Indeed, that works, however, there are two things (first, see the [image](https://imgur.com/a/4JDnjFA), original image on the left, result.png on the right): (1) I’d like to keep the transparency there where I marked it on the original image; (2) on the result image, there is some white which was not in the original image. Is there a way to fix these two issues? :)