# Validate paperclip transparency

Tags: ruby, paperclip

Is it possible to validate that a png image does not have transparency in it using the paperclip gem? I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find out how to do this. I am currently just using a front end javascript solution for this but I'd prefer not to rely on client side validation.

Answer (score 0):

`paperclip` use imagemagick to work(convert, resize) with images. You should use it to detect transparency.

Look into this answer [Detect Alpha Channel with ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581469/detect-alpha-channel-with-imagemagick)

I think will be easier validate uploaded png image before to put it a model with paperclip.